# how to check multiple time validaion

Tags: php

I have an array like below & array would be dynamic.
how to check time is overlap another time of same day

I want to check the time between another time ..days wise

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 02:00 PM
                    [end_time] => 03:00 PM
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 04:00 PM
                    [end_time] => 05:05 PM
                )
 [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 03:30 PM
                    [end_time] => 05:05 PM
                )
        )
    [Sunday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 03:00 PM
                    [end_time] => 04:00 PM
                )
        )
)
```

the single day has multiple time 
I want to check time valid for Monday

For EX. Monday
1. 02:00 PM - 03:00 PM
2. 03:00 PM - 04:00 PM
3. 05:00 PM - 06:00 PM

above is valid time but  if 3 value is

3. 3:30 PM - 05:00 PM

   This is not the valid time 
   I want to check dynamically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Show your attempts on how you check for overlaps. Ask specific questions on what exactly isn't working in your code and what the expected result should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can process one interval at the time, and check if it overlaps a previous one. 
Checking if the start time or the end time is inside any other intervals is enough to find an overlap.

```
$times = array('Monday' => array(
        0 => array('start_time' => '02:00 PM','end_time' => '03:00 PM')
        , 1 => array('start_time' => '03:00 PM','end_time' => '05:05 PM')
        , 2 => array('start_time' => '03:30 PM','end_time' => '05:05 PM')
    )
    , 'Sunday' => array(
        0 => array('start_time' => '03:00 PM','end_time' => '04:00 PM')
    )
);

foreach($times as $dayName => $intervals) // check each day separetely
{
    // keep the indices of the valid intervals (we don't want to check if an interval overlaps an invalid one)
    $validIntervals = array(0); /* no need to check first interval, always valid */

    for($i = 1  ; $i < count($intervals) ; ++$i){
        // parse the data of the interval to test
        $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $intervals[$i]['start_time']);
        $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $intervals[$i]['end_time']);
        $isValid = true ;

        // check if there is a conflict with a previous valid interval
        foreach($validIntervals as $j)
        {
            $validStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $intervals[$j]['start_time']);
            $validEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $intervals[$j]['end_time']);

            if(
                ($start > $validStart and $start < $validEnd) // the start of the interval is inside a previous one
                or
                ($end > $validStart and $end < $validEnd) // the end of the interval is inside a previous one
            )
            {
                // ** your processing of the incorrect interval here ** 
                echo "In day '$dayName', interval $i [" . $intervals[$i]['start_time'] . ', ' . $intervals[$i]['end_time'] . "] overlaps with Interval $j [" . $intervals[$j]['start_time'] . ', ' . $intervals[$j]['end_time'] . "]" ;

                $isValid = false ;
                break ;  // we found one conflict, no need to check for other one
            }
        }

        // no conflict found, the interval is valid
        if($isValid)
            $validIntervals[] = $i ;
    }
}
```